# ReactJS ES6 Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    function Example() {
      // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={**() => setCount(count + 1)**}>
            Click me
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Can someone explain to me the bolded block of code or convert it into ES5. I think I understand the arrow function but guess not.
What I know about arrow function is...
You use it like this,

```
const timesTwo = (a) => { return a*2 } or
const timesTwo = a => a*2 or
const timesTwo = a =>( a*2)
```

I don't understand this piece of code `() => setCount(count + 1)` I understand that count is going to increase as soon as user clicks but is it same as writing

```
function setCount(){
 count: count +1;
}
```

Thank You, I appreciate your time.

Comment: What is it, that you do not understand about `<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>`?

Comment: It doesn't need to be an arrow function. That's there for convenience as it is shorter than writing `function() { setCount(...); }`

Comment: () => setCount(count + 1) just this part.

Comment: that means that your functions is going to execute in the moment that the user clicks, if you are asking for the () => return something is an anonymous function without params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have in the onClick event is equivalent to:

```
function() {
  return setCount(count + 1);
}
```

But you don't need to return the setCount value, so it's better to change it to

```
()=> { setCount(count + 1); }
```

Or just:

```
function() {
  setCount(count + 1);
}
```